# Weird "flutter" in guitar amp when a note is ringing out

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, tone

I recently bought a used guitar (a Sterling JP60) and I just noticed this problem - I am hearing a strange, irritating "flutter" like sound through my amp when a note is ringing out. Particularly obvious on the first two strings, and when the sustained note is after a pull off but also happens during bends and normal playing sometimes. Here is an example

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1GX45TQkB61

Any thoughts on what's causing this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: I would recommend trying to reproduce the problem with a clean sine wave if you think it’s the amp. If it’s not the amp, try making the sound without any distortion or effects.

Answer (score 3):

I've listened to the link and it sounds to me like a problem I had when I blew my speaker. When the voice coil in a speaker over heats they can become warped and start rubbing internally. When that happens, the speaker can respond unevenly as it gets stuck and breaks loose repeatedly.
A good repair technician can be worth his weight in gold when it comes to sorting this kind of thing out.

Comment: I just tested it again and I can hear it through headphones too, but it is a little less obvious through phones

Answer (score 1):

It could be the action (distance from the fretboard) of your 1st and 2nd string is too low and the string is slightly coming into contact with other frets higher up the neck, this can be adjusted with an allen key either by yourself or a guitar tech.
P.S It's hard to tell if that's the issue with all the distortion going on in the clip but that would be my first guess.